# Using ajax to append variable to address bar

Tags: jquery, ajax, history

Is there a way to append the `var url` variable to the address bar without reloading the page. It's my first time using ajax.

Edit: *what is the event target node*
edit 2: got it, much simpler than I thought..

```
history.pushState(null, null, url);


        $('a[href^="/"]').unbind('click').click(function(e){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function( result ){
                    response = $('<div id="temp-ajax-response-holder" style="display: none;"></div>');

                    response.html(result);
                    if (response.find('#ajax').first().find('.header').length > 0 ) $('body').removeClass("home archive").addClass('single');
                    else if(response.find('#ajax').first().find('.archive_title').length > 0 ) $('body').removeClass("home single").addClass('archive')
                    else $('body').removeClass("single archive").addClass('home');
                    if (response.find('#ajax').first().find('.header').length > 0 )
                        $('body').attr('class', 'single single-post');
                    $('body #ajax').html(response.find('#ajax').first().html());
                    bindHTML();
                    response.html('');

                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: This post might be useful... http://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/665261

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing coming to my mind would be the History API. If your browser supports it, you can change the location in the address bar and even make it available through the browser history. This allows to use the back-button for instance.

```
history.pushState(null, null, yourNewUrl);
```

For further introduction I'd recommend reading http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html.

Comment: Like this history.pushState(null, null, url);

Answer (score 0):

YES , There is, Only for browser Supporting HTML 5.

There is a push state.
check this link

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Demo is

http://html5demos.com/history